# Linking to pages in same directory; './page.php' vs. 'page.php'?

Tags: html, web

I always learned to link to pages on the same site I should do the below:

#### Directory Layout

```
/page1.php
/page2.php
/page3.php
/subdir/
       /page4.php
       /page5.php
```

#### On page1.php

```
<a href="./page2.php">Linking to page in same folder</a>
<a href="./subdir/page4.php">Linking to a page one folder deeper</a>
```

#### On page4.php

```
<a href="./page5.php">Linking to page in same folder</a>
<a href="../page3.php">Linking to a page one folder up</a>
```

However, substituting `./page2.php` with just `page2.php` works as well.

```
<a href="page2.php">Linking to page in same folder</a>
```

How is it properly done/which is better? On my personal website, the statistics show a lot of incoming traffic from my own site: is this because I'm using `./` when I don't need to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same. The `.` directory is explicitly "this directory", but if your `href` doesn't start with a `/` or a scheme (`http://` for instance), then it is considered relative to the current directory anyway. It's up to you which to use. Personally I would leave out the `.`, since it serves no purpose, and in my opinion doesn't make it easier to read.